# load .so file use fullPath fail with dotnet3.1 on centos7

Tags: .net-core, centos

I use dotnetcore 3.1 Pinvoke to call my .so file,but it can't be load.I used myLibraryFullPath to load it.What can i do to load this .so file?
i can post image,[this is file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsHiZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved this problem.Put the so file in the Program root directory ,and use this code to import what function you want.

```
[DllImport("getIdle.so", EntryPoint = "getIdleTime")]
private static extern IntPtr getIdleTime();
```

Comment: Please don't post images as ans.

Comment: ok,I will update this ans